# how to check if closing the excel (workbook) vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a code that can return a `boolean` `0`,`1` or `true` or `false`, so that it can recognise if someone closes the excel by clicking on X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the VBA Editor, then go on `ThisWorkbook` (in the project tree on the left-side of the IDE) and you will access the code of the workbook events.

Then, from the dropdown list on the right-top select the event `BeforeClose` after having selected the `Workbook` object in the left-top dropdown menu, and you will get the following code on the module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

That macro will be called every time someone tries to close the Workbook.
There, you can put a global variable to control the action, something like:

```
someoneIsClosing = True '<-- this is a globally defined variable
Cancel = True '<-- if you want to cancel the closing action
myMacro '<-- if you want to go back to "myMacro", i.e. any macro of your project and delegate it from handling the event.
```